# Struts2 - How to use <s:url> inside <s:select> to create hyperlinks?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, enums, struts-tags

I have a `<s:select list="links" headerKey="" headerValue="-- Select a link --" name="reportLinks" id="reportLinks" listValue="linkText" listKey="linkValue" />` and I would like the options to be generated with its value attribute equals to the link that is mapped in an enum.

**The enum:**

```
public enum LinksRelatorios {

    1("One", "/reports", "inicializeReportOne", "PROJECT"),
    2("Two", "/reports", "inicializeReportTwo", "PROJECT"),
    3("Three", "/reports", "inicializeReportThree", "PROJECT"),
    4("four", "/reports", "inicializeReportFour", "PROJECT"),
    5("Five", "/reports", "inicializeReportFive", "PROJECT"),
    6("Six", "/reports", "inicializeReportSix", "PROJECT"),
    7("Seven", "/reports", "inicializeReportSeven", "PROJECT");

    private String linkText;
    private String nameSpace;
    private String action;
    private String project;

    private LinksRelatorios(final String textoLinkParam, final String nameSpaceParam, final String actionParam, final String projectParam) {
        this.linkText = linkTextParam;
        this.nameSpace = nameSpaceParam;
        this.action = actionParam;
        this.project = projectParam;
    }

    public String getLinkText() {
        return this.linkText;
    }

    public String getNameSpace() {
        return this.nameSpace;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return this.action;
    }

    public String getProjeto() {
        return this.project;
    }
```

What I want to do is that every option has the value of a `<s:url namespace="namespace" action="action" />` for example.

The `<s:url>` tag generates a URL with the project context and the action extension for me and that's why I need it, so as not to hard coded this informations in the enum.

My action is correct and I can get the enum without a problem, I tested using `<s:iterator>`.

**The action:**

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class InicioAction extends BaseAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1161409943678292285L;

    private static final LinksRelatorios[] links = LinksRelatorios.values();

    public String inicio() {
        this.addActionMessage(this.getText("msg.sucesso.saudacao.mensagem", new String[] { (String) BaseAction
                .getSession().getAttribute(Constantes.PERFIL) }));
        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }

    public static LinksRelatorios[] getLinks() {
        return InicioAction.links;
    }
}
```

I've searched over google and SO, but couldn't find any results.

I've read the online official docs in http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/using-struts-2-tags.html, http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/a.html and http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/url.html but the examples sections is actually pretty poor comparing to frameworks such as PrimeFaces or RichFaces that have built theirs own showcases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what I was trying to do is possible using just struts tags.

So I just did what's below:

```
<select id="linksInternacaoDomiciliar" name="linksInternacaoDomiciliar">
    <s:iterator value="links" var="link">
        <option value="<s:url namespace="%{#link.nameSpace}" action="%{#link.action}" />"><s:property value="textoLink"/></option>
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

Comment: sure you could have used the "var" attribute on the s:url tag in an iterator and then referenced that how ever you needed. So yes it was possible with the struts2 tags, but there isn't anything wrong with your solution. It is quite obvious/readable and that's what matters.

Comment: I did all those things you said except use the "var" attribute on the s:url tag. The s:url is inside the s:iterator block. Could you post your comment as an answer to be more clear on what you're trying to describe?